# Take action after forked application crash

Tags: c++, unix, process, fork, posix

I want to do one thing, but I don't know it this is possible.

My app starts with some messages in the console

```
std::cout << "appStart" << std:endl
```

after that, a child Qt process do draws in the framebuffer (the screen). If there is a fail in my Qt process, I'm able to capture it and kill the Qt process, and I want to show a message in the console

```
std::cout << "app CRASH!" << std:endl
```

but the screen is frozen with the last content draw by Qt and my message is not shown in the screen. How could clear the screen and show the console again to see my message?

Comment: How are you starting the child process that you want to monitor? If you are using [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html), you can watch the `finished()` signal to find out if it exited normally or crashed. (Also, on Windows 10, if you click and highlight anything in a console window, it freezes the window from adding more text. Make sure you're not doing that accidentally. It has tripped me up more than once.)

Comment: Please elaborate about "If there is a fail in my Qt process, I'm able to capture it and kill the Qt process".

Comment: It's not relevant for the question...This is a simplification of the problem. My Qt child process has finished and I want to clean the screen and se my std:cout messages again. This is possible?

Comment: @XabiE, How exactly are you starting your child process?

Comment: The main process (console process) start the Qt process with a fork. This is relevant? @Mike

Comment: @XabiE, yes, sure, this is the most relevant fact! but this can't be true, as [`fork()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) is used to duplicate the calling process (i.e. you can't start a different application using `fork()`, you can only create a another instance of your process using `fork()`..). Did you mean something else?

Comment: @XabiE It sounds like your question should be framed in terms of POSIX process handling. The Qt, cout, and framebuffer tags are not relevant here unless you're wanting to switch process control technologies. (Update: I changed the tags.)

Comment: I'm not sure. Once I kill the Qt (framebuffer) process (kill(pid, SIGKILL);) the screen is frozen with the last Qt operation instead of show the console again.

Comment: @XabiE So is the problem that the child process is affecting the global system state (namely, the display is taken over by the child), and you want to undo some of these global operations so you can see the console again? If so, you'll have to describe how the child commandeers the system resources. The answer will likely be to save the old state before forking the child, and then restoring the original state in the parent process when the child dies. Or make the child not crash. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found the problem. The issue was the kill method of the child process. Previously i closed the graphical process with

```
SIGKILL     9   /* Kill, unblockable (POSIX).  */
```

And the process stopped without any control, leaving the screen status. With

```
#define SIGTERM     15  /* Termination (ANSI).  */
```

the process is stopped correctly and the control is returned to my main program.